# Definition of connected sets (Baby Rudin)

Tags: real-analysis, definition, connectedness

In Baby Rudin a subset E of a metric space X is defined to be connected if "E is not a union of two nonempty separated sets."

This may be nit picking, but should this not be

E is not a union of two or more seperated sets

?

Wikipedia agrees. To be super nit picking, by Rudin's definition (and taking it super literally) a set that is the union of three nonempty separated sets would be connected since... two is not equal to three.

Comment: If it is the union of three separated sets $A, B, C$, then it is the union of two separated sets $A, D$ where $D = B \cup C$

Answer (score 1):

> a set that is the union of three nonempty separated sets would be connected since... two is not equal to three.

A positive number is defined as being greater than $0$. If $x>1$, then can we say that $x$ is not positive since $1$ is not equal to $0$?

A set that is the union of three separated sets is also a union of two separated sets.